# Problem with "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"

Tags: vuejs3, laravel-9, inertiajs, element-ui, element-plus

I try to delete the row but I can't I have already tested my model and my controller but with the element-ui table I can't, help please ?

im using Inertiajs with Ziggy route , laravel 9 and vue3

the error : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

i try delete the row directly without model the same problem

**the Script :**

```
const props = defineProps({
  clients: Array,
  client: Object,
})
const confirmingClientDeletion = ref(false)
const form = useForm()
const confirmClientDeletion = () => {
  confirmingClientDeletion.value = true
  setTimeout(250)
}
const deleteClient = () => {
  form.delete(route('clients.destroy', props.client.id), {
    preserveScroll: true,
    onSuccess: () => closeModal(),
    onFinish: () => form.reset(),
  })
}
const closeModal = () => {
  confirmingClientDeletion.value = false
  form.reset()
}
```

**the template :**

```
   <div class="px-2">
    <div class="md:container-2xl rounded-lg bg-white shadow-lg text-gray-700 text-l font-medium mb-4">
      <div class="p-12 content-center">
        <el-table :data="clients" style="width: 100%">
          <el-table-column prop="id" label="id" width="180" />
          <el-table-column prop="companyname" label="Raison Sociale" width="180" />
          <el-table-column prop="town" label="Ville" width="120" />
          <el-table-column prop="created_at" label="Date de creation" width="150" />
          <el-table-column fixed="right" label="Operations" width="200">
            <template #default>
              <el-button size="small">Modifier</el-button>
              <el-button size="small" type="danger" @click="confirmClientDeletion">Supprimer</el-button>
            </template>
          </el-table-column>
        </el-table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <DialogModal :show="confirmingClientDeletion" @close="closeModal">
    <template #title> Suppression des clients </template>

    <template #content> Vous êtes sûr de vouloir supprimer définitivement le client? </template>

    <template #footer>
      <SecondaryButton @click="closeModal"> Annuler </SecondaryButton>

      <DangerButton
        class="ml-3"
        :class="{ 'opacity-25': form.processing }"
        :disabled="form.processing"
        @click="deleteClient"
      >
        Supprimer client
      </DangerButton>
    </template>
  </DialogModal>
```

**Destroy function in The controller :**

```
public function destroy(Client $client)
    {
        $client->delete();
        return redirect()->route('clients.index');
 
    }
```

Comment: can u try to do `dd($client->delete());` instead of `$client->delete()`, so u can see if the model is actually deleted or not. if deleted, will show up `true`. or u can try to dd the model, simple debugging

Comment: thanx but dd($client->delete()) show nothing

Comment: will show null, true or false, but saying that shows nothing doesnt help the helper help u

Comment: thank you for your help,   nothing happens when i click at delete still have the same err  props.client is undefined, any idea ? thanks a lot

Comment: show me the controller method for rendering the view

Comment: public function destroy(Client $client)
    {
        $client->delete();
        return redirect()->route('clients.index');